# SQL table join where single id has multiple results

Tags: sql

I am using a SQL query to display products from my database with a single preview image for each. For this I'm using a table join to combine the images table with the products.

The problem I am having is that multiple images are applied to each product id and as such, I am getting duplicates. I simply need to find a workaround that will allow me to get a single image for each product id, without limiting the products themselves.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.description, img.img
FROM product AS prod
LEFT JOIN img 
ON prod.id = img.product_id;
```

For the most part this works, except for the duplicates that are created for each product.

I feel I should also mention that I am displaying the results using php with a PDO command

Comment: instead of `img.img`, how about `SELECT MAX(img.img) AS img,... FROM... GROUP BY prod.id, prod.name, prod.description` - in this case, it will only get one value per `ID`. `MAX` can also be substitued by `MIN`.

Comment: @JohnWoo: i didnt get why should use `max()` function. what is the use of max() here?

Comment: @Prashant `MAX` is an aggregate function which returns single value - which the OP want to get.

Comment: @JohnWoo : i saw this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_max) for reference. i understood **The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column.**

Comment: @Prashant so what's the problem now? Are you asking why I suggested to use `MAX`?

Comment: @JohnWoo : yes, of course. Instead of `LIMIT, SELECT TOP` you are suggesting `max()` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59330/discussion-between-prashant-and-john-woo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do a group by:

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.description, MAX(img.img)
FROM product AS prod
LEFT JOIN img
ON prod.id = img.product_id
GROUP BY prod.id, prod.name, prod.description
```

Or do a correlated sub-select in the select list:

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.description,
       (SELECT MAX(img.img) FROM img WHERE prod.id = img.product_id)
FROM product AS prod
```

Comment: Something so simple as a 'GROUP BY' and it works. NOTE: It only works without 'MAX'